# Writing code to grade a quiz that I created in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to teach myself code and I am currently stuck on a mini project that I am working on. I believe that I have the HTML code worked out; however, I am having difficulty making the Javascript/jQuery do what I would like it to do.

I would like the Javascript/jQuery to score my quiz and print the score on a different page. I am not sure if my syntax is wrong or if I am making the wrong calls or...?

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="center">

<div id="questionContainer">

<div id="header">
<h1>State Capitol Quiz</h1>
</div>

<div id="left">

<form action="quiz.html" class="container">
<div class="blank">
<br />
    <br />
    <p id="one">1.&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;What is the capitol of Michigan?<br />
        <div class="tab">
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="A" />&nbsp;Lansing<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="B" />&nbsp;Richmond<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="C" />&nbsp;Austin<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="D" />&nbsp;Columbus<br />
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
</form>

<form action="quiz.html" class="container">
<div class="blank">
<br />
<br />
    <p id="two">2.&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;What is the capitol of Virginia?<br />
       <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" name="question" value="A" />&nbsp;Lansing<br />
        <input type="radio" name="question" value="B" />&nbsp;Richmond<br />
        <input type="radio" name="question" value="C" />&nbsp;Lincoln<br />
        <input type="radio" name="question" value="D" />&nbsp;Reno<br />
      </div>
    </p>
</div>
</form>

<form action="quiz.html" class="container">
<div class="blank">
<br />
<br />
    <p id="three">3.&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;What is the capitol of Arkansas?<br />
        <div class="tab">  
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="A" />&nbsp;Dallas<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="B" />&nbsp;Lincoln<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="C" />&nbsp;Little Rock<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="D" />&nbsp;Cheyene<br />
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
</form>

<form action="quiz.html" class="container">
<div class="blank">
<br />
<br />
    <p id="four">4.&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;What is the capitol of Arizona?<br />
        <div class="tab"> 
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="A" />&nbsp;Juneau<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="B" />&nbsp;Honolulu<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="C" />&nbsp;Pheonix<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="D" />&nbsp;Toledo<br />
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
</form>

<form action="quiz.html" class="container">
<div class="blank">
<br />
<br />
    <p id="five">5.&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;What is the capitol of Florida?<br /> 
        <div class="tab"> 
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="A" />&nbsp;Oakland<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="B" />&nbsp;Kansas City<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="C" />&nbsp;Tallahassee<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="D" />&nbsp;Miami<br />
    </div>
    </p>
</div>
</form>

<form action="quiz.html" class="container">
<div class="blank">
<br />
<br />
    <p id="six">6.&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;What is the capitol of Nebraska?<br />
        <div class="tab">  
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="A" />&nbsp;Omaha<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="B" />&nbsp;Lincoln<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="C" />&nbsp;Sacramento<br />
        <input type="radio" name="question" value="D" />&nbsp;Sab Diego<br />
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<div id="right">
<form action="quiz.html" class="container">
<br />
<br />
<div class="blank">
    <p id="seven">7.&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;What is the capitol of Texas?<br />
        <div class="tab">    
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="A" />&nbsp;Fortworth<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="B" />&nbsp;Richmond<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="C" />&nbsp;Austin<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="D" />&nbsp;Las Vegas<br />
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
</form>

<form action="quiz.html" class="container">
<div class="blank">
    <p id="eight">8.&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;What is the capitol of Alaska?<br />
        <div class="tab">   
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="A" />&nbsp;Tulsa<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="B" />&nbsp;Oaklahoma City<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="C" />&nbsp;Austin<br />
        <input type="radio" name="question" value="D" />&nbsp;Juneau<br />
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
</form>

<form action="quiz.html" class="container">
<div class="blank">
    <p id="nine">9.&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;What is the capitol of Hawaii?<br /> 
        <div class="tab"> 
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="A" />&nbsp;Paris<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="B" />&nbsp;Honolulu<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="C" />&nbsp;Austin<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="D" />&nbsp;Cadilac<br />
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
</form>

<form action="quiz.html" class="container">
<div class="blank">
    <p id="ten">10.&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;What is the capitol of Ohio?<br />
        <div class="tab">   
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="A" />&nbsp;Cleveland<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="B" />&nbsp;Green Bay<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="C" />&nbsp;Austin<br />
            <input type="radio" name="question" value="D" />&nbsp;Columbus<br />
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
</form>

<div id="buttonDiv">        
    <input type="button" id="button" value="submit" />
</div>


</div>

</div>

</div>

<div class="center">

<div id="answerSheet">
    <p id="score"><h1>Your Score!</h1></p>
    <br />
    <p>Results:</p>
 </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Here is the Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").click(function(){
$("#questionContainer").fadeOut("slow",function(){
    $("#answerSheet").fadeIn("slow",function(){
    });
});

var numQues= 10;
var numChoices= 4;
var answers = new Array(10);

answers[0] = "Lansing";
answers[1] = "Richmond";
answers[2] = "Little Rock";
answers[3] = "Pheonix";
answers[4] = "Tallahassee";
answers[5] = "Lincoln";
answers[6] = "Austin";
answers[7] = "Juneau";
answers[8] = "Honolulu";
answers[9] = "Columbus";

function getScore(form){
var score = 0;
var currElt;
var currSelection;
for(i = 0; i<numQues; i++){
    currElt = i * numChoi;
    for(j = 0; j<numChoi; j++){
        currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
        if(currSelection.checked){
            if(currSelection.value == answers[i]){
                score++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

score = math.round(score/numQues * 100);
form.precentage.value = score + "&#37;";
var corrAnswers = "";
for(i = 1; i <numQues; i++){
    corrAnswers += i + "." + answers [i - 1] + "\r\n;"
}
form.solutions.value = corrAnswers/numQues * 100 + "%";}

});
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Off topic suggestion: `var answers = ["Lansing","Richmond","Little Rock", "Pheonix", "Tallahassee","Lincoln","Austin","Juneau","Honolulu","Columbus"]`

Comment: What is expected behavior, what's the actual behavior, error messages? What are the steps to reproduce. What is the problem you're facing? Please take some time to learn how to ask questions that are easier to answer, no one wants to dig through 100 lines of JS/HTML. http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grade Quiz After Submit Button is Clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139219/grade-quiz-after-submit-button-is-clicked) or [Still Stuck on Grading my Quiz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180542/still-stuck-on-grading-my-quiz)

Comment: yeah, reposting over and over wont get answers, well written questions will

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AzBsJ/1/ - in case anybody fancies it. You don't even call your getScore method and I can't see how it's going to work anyway since each set of your radio buttons is wrapped in a form element.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to use the HTML structure and jQuery to help you:

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Dkdrh/

Click answers to the questions (right or wrong) and then hit the "Score" button below to get it to calculate the score for you.  Here's the code:

```
// text value and then question answer value
var answers = [
    "Lansing", "A",
    "Richmond", "B",
    "Little Rock", "C",
    "Phoenix", "C",
    "Tallahassee", "C",
    "Lincoln", "B",
    "Austin", "C",
    "Juneau", "D",
    "Honolulu", "B",
    "Columbus", "D"
];

function calcScore() {
    var results = {right: 0, wrong: 0, answered: [], unanswered: [], missed: []};
    $("form .tab").each(function(index) {
        var chosen = $(this).find("input:checked");
        if (chosen.length) {
            results.answered.push(index);
            if (chosen.val() == answers[(index * 2) + 1]) {
                results.right++;
                results.answered.push(index);
            } else {
                results.wrong++;
                results.missed.push(index);
            }
        } else {
            results.unanswered.push(index);
        }
    });
    return(results);
}

$("#buttonDiv").click(function() {
    var results = calcScore();
    var str = "Correct: " + results.right + ", Wrong: " + results.wrong + ", Unanswered: " + results.unanswered.length;
    $("#results").html(str);
});
```

Some notes about the code:

1. The answers are stored in a single array with both text value and letter value for easy comparison.  You do `2 * index` to get the text answer and `(2 * index) + 1` to get the letter value for the answer.
2. The `calcScore()` function returns you number right, number wrong, number unanswered and an array of answered correct, answered incorrect and unanswered question numbers.
3. The `calcScore()` function uses the structure of the HTML to keep track of the question number automatically.

---

I did not entirely follow what you were trying to do with your code, but a big issue I saw is that you were comparing the text value in your answers array to the `.value` of the radio buttons, but the radio button values are set to `"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"` and `"D"` so they would never match the text you had in your array.

---

FYI, if you want to see a different way that uses more natural formatting in HTML, see the HTML and CSS here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/H26c8/.  Hint: It uses an ordered list to automatically number the ordered list of questions.